# nc -L disconnect after transmission

Tags: unit-testing, netcat, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently preparing a unit test and therefore I need to emulate a client server connection.
I tried doing it like this:

```
nc -l 6543 < dummy-result.txt
```

But netcat does not close the connection after returning the content of the file. So my client is waiting for the server to close the connection endlessly.
Does anyone know how to get ncat to close the connection after serving the file? Also it would be useful to have ncat serve this file (and close the connection) for multiple requests (aka. -k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was a bug in the openbsd implementation of netcat.
The option -N (server side) did not terminate the connection if the client was another netcat. If the client was telnet, it terminated as expected (Now I'm using the nmap netcat and it works).

For handling multiple connections I used a simple "while true" loop around it.